# Check if the given function is one one and onto.

Tags: calculus

Let $C^{∞} (0,1)$ stand for the set of all real valued functions on $(0,1)$ that have derivatives of all order. Then the map $C^{∞} (0,1) \to C^{∞}(0,1)$ given by $f \to f + df/dt$ is onto and one one$?$

The map in not one one since it sends $e^{-x}$ and $\frac{e^{-x}}{2}$ to zero.

How can I check if the map onto$?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are essentially supposed to do is to solve the linear ODE $f + f' = g$. There is a formula for this (via the variation of constant method):
$$f'(t) = ce^{-t} + e^{-t}\int_0^t g(s)e^{s} \, \mathrm{d}s$$
for any $c \in \mathbb{R}$. It is an easy computation that this indeed solves the ODE. From this is follows that your function is onto but not one to one.

Comment: How does this conclude that the function is onto$?$

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

$f(t)=e^{-t}$, $g(t)=-e^{-t}$ gives
$$
f(t) + f'(t) = e^{-t}-e^{-t} = g'(t)+g(t)
$$
so the map is not injective.